# Can clojure convert string representing a sequence back to a sequence?

Tags: string, clojure, escaping, sequence

I can convert a string to a sequence, and then convert that sequence to a string representing the sequence.

```
user=> (str (first (list (seq "(xy)z"))))
"(\\( \\x \\y \\) \\z)"
```

I can also insert apply into the above form to get the original string back

```
user=> (apply str (first (list (seq "(xy)z"))))
"(xy)z"
```

but is there a way to convert a string representing a sequence, to the sequence that the string represents?  such as:

```
"(\\( \\x \\y \\) \\z)"
user=> (some-fn2 "(\\( \\x \\y \\) \\z)")
(\( \x \y \) \z \))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `read-string` function reads a string into a Clojure expression.

```
(read-string "(\\( \\x \\y \\) \\z)")
(\( \x \y \) \z)
```

The read family of functions are a big part of what makes Clojure a lisp and the whole "everything is data" mindset. You can read any form with them:

```
(read-string "{:a 1 :b 3 :c (1 2 3)}")
{:a 1, :b 3, :c (1 2 3)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.  I feel like a guy who was given a fish, but knows he needs to learn to fish.  I am still struggling with how to find the clojure functions I know must exist by searching various clojure resources.  read-string was nowhere on my radar.